What is the correct browser behaviour when you have CSS shorthands in combination with individual shorthand constituents?
Consider the following code.


a {
  text-decoration-color: red;
}

.oops{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

code {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
  padding-inline: 0.5em;
}
<p>This <a href='#'>link</a> is underlined in red with <code>text-decoration-color: red</code>.</p>

<p>This <a href='#' class="oops">link</a> also has <code>text-decoration-color: red</code> applied, but is not underlined in red in Chrome or Firefox as it has <code>text-decoration: underline</code> applied, which is a short hand for <ul>
  <li>text-decoration-color</li>
  <li>text-decoration-line</li>
  <li>text-decoration-style</li>
  <li>text-decoration-thickness</li>
</ul></p>



If you view this in Chrome or Firefox, the 2nd link is not underlined in red, as text-decoration-color is overridden by the text-decoration-shorthand (even though color is not specified as part of it). In Safari, it is underlined in red, as text-decoration-color overrides the shorthand.
The discrepancy can be easily resolved by changing text-decoration: underline to text-decoration-line: underline, but I am wondering... which is the correct behaviour here according to the spec?

Chrome and Firefox are the correct ones.

This is an interesting question... It appears to come from how Safari breaks up a shorthand (e.g text-decoration) into it's constituent properties (e.g. text-decoration-color, text-decoration-line, etc.)
@TemaniAfif what makes you say that Chrome/FF are the correct ones (other than the fact that Google is well known for "getting it right" and Safari often goes there own way for a while)? Are there some links you could share that would help?

@Harrison that's how CSS is supposed to work since when it was invented (not only with text-decoration but any shorthand property)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#omitting_properties: "Omitting properties: A value which is not specified is set to its initial value. That means that it overrides previously set values." - text-decoration: underline omits specifying a color, so text-decoration-color will be reset to its initial value. The initial value for that property is currentcolor.

It's as I suspected, but confirmed in the question comments ( by @TemaniAfif, and linked by @C3Roe)

Omitting properties: A value which is not specified is set to its initial value. That means that it overrides previously set values.

Source
By using text-decoration (the shorthand), you're effectively setting each of the constituent properties to initial.
See the example below:

.second and .third have the same effect
.fourth has the desired effect (from your example) in that it doesn't override the previously set values



a {
  text-decoration-color: red;

}

.second {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.third {
  text-decoration-color: initial;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: initial;
  text-decoration-thickness: initial;
}

.fourth {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}
<a href='#'>First</a>
</br>
<a href='#' class="second">Second</a>
</br>
<a href='#' class="third">Third</a>
</br>
<a href='#' class="fourth">Fourth</a>



As for Safari...
From what I've seen in the Safari Elements panel, it appears that when using the shorthand for a property text-decoration, Safari will attempt to split that property into it's constituent properties.

